# Implementing pipeline tasks in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
      inputs:
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
```

I have a `NugetCommand@2` as a task I declared in yaml pipeline. is it possible to parameterise the `NuGetCommand@2`?

Comment: To me it's unclear what you're asking. Can you edit the question to provide an example of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you are asking if you an parameterize the name of the task you can't. However the task can be a template and still have one place to update and maintian.